# How to give height to an image without stretching

Tags: html, css

I have an image with which has a very high resolution.
I set the width to 100% and it works fine. The only problem is that its too big in height I'm not being able to give a height without stretching the image.

Here my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="Post1.jpg" alt=""> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div{
  max-height:500px
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  max-height:100%;
}
```

How can I give it proper height without stretching the image?

Comment: put `width` and `height` auto would do the job!

Comment: Where exactlty?I just tried and it didn't really work.
Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..add image instead of inner div, If you have to give width 100%.

```css
.sq1 {
   height : 300px;width:300px;
  background-color:#eee;position:fixed;
}

.sq2{
  height:200px;width:200px;
  background-color:#000;margin:50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sq1">
  <div class="sq2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* css */
    div{
      height:500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    img{
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
    }

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="Post1.jpg" alt=""> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code and the image remains with it's default height(too big).

Comment: I have updated my code, try it out. On the other side, @WosleyAlarico could try changing the `height` based on your need

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are several flaws in your code.

1. The .div selector selects anything with class="div". You want to use the .container selector
2. You forgot to close max-height:500px with a ;
3. Finally the answer to you question: Your image still shows in the original size. this is because you haven't set overflow: hidden; By adding this line the image does not display outside of the .container div.

I tried to stick as close to the original post as possible. Keep in mind you are cutting off a part of the image which may lead to undesired results.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="Post1.jpg" alt=""> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container{
  max-height:500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It's not really that way because is hiding image content. The aim is to be able to decrease the height without stretching the image or hiding any content.

Comment: If you want to keep a specific width. There is no way to change an image without stretching it or cutting some part off. Quite logical as this is simply not possible in real life as well. You can however do something simular to background-size: contain;. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain Provided you don't mind empty spaces at the sides of your image (and thus change the width).

Comment: @RMo.Thanks. Will then crop the images. Can't put it on the background because its a slider.

Comment: But you can replicate the behaviours that css applies to backgrounds. Like applying max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; and improve it from there. (this example works very limited without further improvements).